# Custom Providers, Best Practices, and Configuration Conflaguration

Tags: asp.net, provider

I have been building web sites with ASP.NET for a while now. At first I avoided learning the intricacies of the ASP.NET Provider Model. Instead I used the canned providers where necessary, and leaned heavily on Dependency Injection frameworks for all my other needs.

Recently however, I have been writing pluggable components for ASP.NET and of course writing lots of custom provider based solutions in order to make that happen. It has become quickly apparent to me however, that a lot of [initialization code is being duplicated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479028.aspx), which is a bad thing.

So...

1. Are there any best practices that have emerged on how to avoid the configuration spaghetti code?
2. Have you built, or have any examples (base/helper classes, custom attributes, reflection) to share of abstracting the basic initialization code out so building custom providers is easier?

**NOTE:**

Please do not try and send me to the [Provider Toolkit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/asp.net/aa336558.aspx) site. I have already exhausted that resource, which is why I am turning to the SO Community :)

Comment: I would like to offer some help, but I am not really clear on something. You are writing "pluggable components" for ASP.NET, and "of course" writing lots of custom provider-based solutions... I am not sure exactly what you mean by pluggable component, or why its obvious that you would write different providers for each component. Could you clarify what it is you are trying to do, and why you need a different provider for each component? I'll see if I can offer some help.

Comment: Have you seen ELMAH? I have been striving to write components that are cross-cutting in their concerns, but not domain/application specific. Modules, Handlers, etc... If they touch any kind of storage they need to utilize the provider model to be truly pluggable (machine.config/web.config). This is not a problem, but I notice that you end up writing a lot of code to just manage the config stuff. I was just wondering if anyone had done this enough to  come up with some best practices, or even some utility methods for generically handling this type of plumbing code.

Comment: It is like the double locking pattern for caching in a web environment. If you do anything with the cache you end up writing that code, but you usually factor it into some utility class to do the heavy lifting for you so you don't have to write it twice. There are a lot of things you end up doing while managing the config sections, and I was just wondering if any patterns had emerged specifically for this issue. I just want to be as DRY as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I just did a rough implementation of rather basic implementation of the membership and role providers, and I don't have any code duplication at all!

I have divided everything into three projects (plus tests):

- Application - asp.net mvc app. models, controllers etc.
- Infrastructure - IoC and Interfaces
- Infrastructure.Web - Providers

The model for User and Role implement interfaces from Infrastructure and those classes get registered to the IoC on application startup. The providers then asks the IoC to resolve the classes and does it's thing. This way I can add things to the model and user interface yet using the same providers. The one problem I've noticed, is that the web being launched by the "ASP.NET Configuration"-button can't use the providers, as the setup is being done in Application_Start and the "ASP.NET Configuration" is another web. I don't see this as a problem though.

Comment: I am specifically trying to build pluggable components that can be dropped into any ASP.Net project. I would LOVE to use an IoC, but that would rule out the ability for a single DLL that can be dropped into a project and work.

Comment: Include a mini IoC in your component, have the app register a factory that implements a interface in your component, and exposes methods to build the respective classes.